# I have a problem calling a method using Form Request outside of its controller--laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

```
> //Some other service trying to call the store method in the cart
> controller $cart = new CartController; 
> $addToCart = $cart->store($request);
> 
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> //Cart Controller (It uses a form request to validate) public function
> store(StoreCartRequest $request) {        
>     //the code fails, but if I remove the form request, it works       
>     dd('done');
> }
```

##Error Message below

```
"message": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\CartController::store(): Argument #1 ($request) must be of type App\\Http\\Requests\\StoreCartRequest, App\\Http\\Requests\\StoreOrderRequest given, called in C:\\Users\\mgbem\\Documents\\SYSTEMTECH PROJECTS\\laslas\\laslas_order_module\\app\\Repositories\\OrderRepository.php on line 42",
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTcM3.png)

Comment: please post the error, as text, not an image.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... my first thought would be to not be calling a Controller method at all but have you tried using the Service Container to call the method (Method Invocation & Injection)?

Answer (score 2):

As error said

```
 $addToCart = $cart->store($request);
```

`$request` you passing here is the instance of `App\\Http\\Requests\\StoreOrderRequest`.

But in controller you have given `$request` type as `App\\Http\\Requests\\StoreCartRequest`:

```
 store(StoreCartRequest $request) {
```

If you are using `php 8.0` or higher version, you can use multiple type hints like:

```
store(StoreCartRequest|StoreOrderRequest $request) {
```

**Personal opinion**

If you gonna use one method more than one time it is always better to offload it to service class. Do not call controller method in another service class at all.

Comment: +1 for personal opinion, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DBMRByJUmU How to work with services in laravel